# I'm intgreting an add/remove command to my ticket system & the error is "docs.Members.ID.push(Member.id); is not a function", is it a mongoose issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a ticket system Discord bot and everything works fine except the "/add" command. I have the database schema setup to where it stores the guildid, membersid, ticketid, channelid, etc, followed by the the initial ticket with a "close", "lock", "unlock", and "claim" buttons, which to this point all works just fine. Within the ticket, I'm trying to integrate a slash command where I can add and remove members to the ticket and in the tickets the four buttons work, and the remove slash commands works with both removing the actual member and the interaction reply that says "The member is not associated with this ticket", but the bot breaks at the "/add" option. I've tested possible debugs like making the "MembersID" a string which gives me the error "docs.Members.ID.push(Member.id); is not a function" and I also tried making the "MembersID" an array by writing "MembersID": [String] and I get the following error "The field 'MembersID' must be an array but is of type string in document". Below is my code.

Ticket.js - (Schema)

````
module.exports = model(
    "Tickets", 
    new Schema ({
        GuildID: String,
        MembersID: String,
        TicketID: String,
        ChannelID: String,
        Closed: Boolean,
        Locked: Boolean,
        Type: String,
        Claimed: Boolean,
        ClaimedBy: String
    })
)```


Actions.js
```const { MessageEmbed, CommandInteraction} = require("discord.js");
const DB = require("../../Structures/Schemas/Tickets");

module.exports = {
    name: "actions",
    description: "Ticket Actions.",
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    options: [
        {
            name: "action",
            type: "STRING",
            description: "Add or Remove a member from this ticket.",
            required: true,
            choices: [
                { name: "Add", value: "add" },
                { name: "Remove", value: "remove" },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: "member",
            description: "Select the Member(s)",
            type: "USER",
            required: true,
        },
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(interaction) {
        const { guildId, options, channel } = interaction;

        const Action = options.getString("action");
        const Member = options.getMember("member");

        const Embed = new MessageEmbed();

        switch(Action) {
            case "add":
                DB.findOne({ GuildID: guildId, ChannelID: channel.id}, async (err, docs) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    if(!docs)
                    return interaction.reply({ 
                        embeds: [
                            Embed.setColor("#5104DB").setDescription(
                                "⛔ | This channel is not tied with a ticket."
                    ),
                ],
                ephemeral: true,
            });
            if (docs.MembersID.includes(Member.id))
                return interaction.reply({ 
                    embeds: [
                        Embed.setColor("#5104DB").setDescription(
                            "⛔ | This member has already been added to this ticket."
                    ),
                ],
                ephemeral: true,
            });
            docs.MembersID.push(Member.id);

            channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(Member.id, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: true,
                VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
                READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true,
            });

            interaction.reply({ 
                embeds: [
                    Embed.setColor("#5104DB").setDescription(
                        `✅ | ${Member} has been added to this ticket.`
                    ),
                ],
            });
            docs.save();
        }
    );
                break;

            case "remove":
                DB.findOne({ GuildID: guildId, ChannelID: channel.id}, async (err, docs) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    if(!docs)
                    return interaction.reply({ 
                        embeds: [
                            Embed.setColor("#5104DB").setDescription(
                                "⛔ | This channel is not tied with a ticket."
                    ),
                ],
                ephemeral: true,
            });
            if(!docs.MembersID.includes(Member.id))
                return interaction.reply({ 
                    embeds: [
                        Embed.setColor("#5104DB").setDescription(
                            "⛔ | This member is not associated with this ticket."
                    ),
                ],
                ephemeral: true,
            });
            docs.MembersID.remove(Member.id);

            channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(Member.id, {
                VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
            });

            interaction.reply({ 
                embeds: [
                    Embed.setColor("#5104DB").setDescription(
                        `✅ | ${Member} has been removed from this ticket.`
                    ),
                ],
            });
            docs.save();
        }
    );
                break;
        }
    },
};```
````

Comment: `MembersID` seems to be of type `string` and a `string` does not have a `push` function

Comment: I also made it an array in my schema by typing "MembersID": [String] to make it an array and get the error "The field 'MembersID' must be an array but is of type string in document", but when I type "MembersID": String and the error is "docs.Members.ID.push(Member.id);

Comment: To make it Array you just type `Array` not `[String]`

Comment: I just tested this and it does make the add/remove commands work, but then makes the buttons that calls to docs.Membersid invalid with an error that says "Specified parameter is not a user nor role" any ideas as to why? Within my schemas it needs to be an array of strings hence why I tried [String], "String", makes everything within the ticket system work except add/remove commands and "Array" allows everything but the "Lock" & "Unlock" buttons work